# SQL many sysdate in a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a big query with many sysdate, everytime i must check for some sysdate ( +1 +2 +3 etc) i must change in every part and i lost many time, i'd like to create a variable or something on top of my query with unique sysdate who change every sysdate in the query.

this is a little part as example

```
SELECT DISTINCT(COD) 
      FROM TABLE_COD 
      WHERE START_DATE <= trunc(sysdate + 5) 
      AND END_DATE >= trunc(sysdate + 5)
      AND VALUE = 1
      AND (COD_REF = ( SELECT to_char(sysdate + 5, 'D') FROM dual)  OR  COD_REF = 0)
.......continue
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: What do you mean, "change the sysdate"?

Comment: this is a little part SELECT DISTINCT(COD) 
      FROM TABLE_COD 
      WHERE START_DATE <= trunc(sysdate + 5) 
      AND END_DATE >= trunc(sysdate + 5)
      AND VALUE = 1
      AND (COD_REF = ( SELECT to_char(sysdate + 5, 'D') FROM dual)  OR  COD_REF = 0)

Answer (score 1):

You can join the date:

```
select ...
from ...
cross join (select trunc(sysdate) + 5 as mydate from dual)
where start_date <= mydate
and end_date >= mydate
and value = 1
and cod_ref in (to_char(mydate, 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'), 0)
...
```

Please see also that I added the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` to `TO_CHAR`, because otherwise the output would be session-dependent (i.e. one session may regard Sunday the first day of the week, another Monday).

Comment: @nowaySync: Can you tell me what's wrong with my answer? You asked Gordon how to change his query he posted an hour later than I posted mine, so as to have to change only one number. Why don't you use my answer where it *is* only one number already? Is there anything you don't understand about my answer? Or what else is missing?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need something like this.

```
with sysdate_plus_n as 
(select sysdate+1 as sysdate_plus_1 ,-- other variables
        sysdate+5 as sysdate_plus_5 from dual)
--This is a temporary table. So if you query 
--(select sysdate_plus_5 from sysdate_plus_n), you will get sysdate+5
--You can change your values in this temporary table

SELECT DISTINCT(COD) 
      FROM TABLE_COD 
      WHERE START_DATE <= trunc(select sysdate_plus_5 from sysdate_plus_n) 
      AND END_DATE >= trunc(select sysdate_plus_5 from sysdate_plus_n)
      AND VALUE = 1
      AND (COD_REF = ( SELECT to_char(select sysdate_plus_5 from sysdate_plus_n, 'D')
      FROM dual)  OR  COD_REF = 0)
.......continue
```

Now just change values in the temporary table. You dont have to touch the query.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **substitution variable** i.e. `&` and enter the value when prompted. Thus, you will enter the value only once and it will be used simultaneously everywhere in the code.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT &dt FROM dual;
Enter value for dt: SYSDATE
old   1: SELECT &dt FROM dual
new   1: SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual

SYSDATE
---------
23-DEC-15

SQL> /
Enter value for dt: SYSDATE +5
old   1: SELECT &dt FROM dual
new   1: SELECT SYSDATE +5 FROM dual

SYSDATE+5
---------
28-DEC-15
```

> AND (COD_REF = ( SELECT to_char(sysdate + 5, 'D') FROM dual)  OR  COD_REF = 0)

On a side note, you don't have to use a **sub-query** all the time. **SYSDATE** is an in-built function, so you can call it directly. No need to select it from dual.

```
AND (COD_REF = to_char(sysdate + 5, 'D') OR  COD_REF = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple days at a time, how about writing one query for the purpose?  Something like this:

```
WITH params AS (
      SELECT 5 as val FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 6 as val FROM DUAL
     )
SELECT DISTINCT v.val, COD
FROM params CROSS JOIN
     TABLE_COD c
WHERE START_DATE <= trunc(sysdate + params.val) AND END_DATE >= trunc(sysdate + params.val) AND
      VALUE = 1 AND
      (COD_REF = (to_char(sysdate + params.val, 'D') OR  COD_REF = 0);
```

With this structure, you can add as many values as you want to the query (including only one).

Comment: is possible create only a simple variable on top ? example val = 5 ? the reseach for me is variable, in some days i must check for sysdate + 5 in other sysdate + 32 and i must replace in the query only the number.

Comment: @nowaySync . . . Yes, `params` can have only one row with only one value, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the value of SYSDATE is evaluated only once before the query is actually ran. In other words, the value of SYSDATE will stay constant throughout your complete query. Knowing this detail may greatly help or solve your question.

**I do think the best solution in your case would be to create a user function to be called as many times as you want from within your select statement. Then, when you need any changes, just update the function instead.**

I don't think there's a way to create a variable at the beginning of your query in order to be reused through out a single statement. You can however, use the WITH clause in order to avoid repeating embedded queries and improve performance and ease of reading. This is similar to what you need, but wanted to mention it as it might be a solution too depending on your needs.

Check out this link for more information on Oracle Functions:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH FIX_SYSDATE AS
    (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS FIXED_SYSDATE
       FROM DUAL)
SELECT DISTINCT(COD) 
  FROM TABLE_COD
       CROSS JOIN FIX_SYSDATE FS
 WHERE START_DATE <= FS.FIXED_SYSDATE + 5
   AND END_DATE >= FS.FIXED_SYSDATE + 5
   AND VALUE = 1
   AND (COD_REF = (SELECT TO_CHAR(FS.FIXED_SYSDATE + 5, 'D') 
                     FROM DUAL)
        OR COD_REF = 0)
.......continue
```

Fix TRUNC(SYSDATE) or simply SYSDATE (I don't know the remaining of your query, since there is "... continue" there) and then use it as many times as required on your main query.